# Dynamic keys using Immutable.js

Tags: javascript, redux, immutable.js

I'm using Redux, but NOT React to provide a bit of context. I have a situation where I would like to store some data about pages a user has visited, but it seems like I need to set my schema prior to setting any new state in a reducer.

```
function reducer(state, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case STORE_CATEGORY:
            return Object.assign(
                {}, state,{
                    [action.category] : {
                        pages: [],
                        filters: {}
                    }
                }
            );
    }
}
```

The above function works, but I want to translate updating the state with an undetermined set of keys using immutable.js where the keys will be named after the category visited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, the `Map` from Immutable would be good for you issue

```
const initalState = Immutable.Map();

function reducer(state = initalState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case STORE_CATEGORY:
      return state.set(action.category, {
        pages: [],
        filters: {}
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! However, I have an odd situation where initialState's declaration outside of the function throws an error
    
`Uncaught TypeError: state.set is not a function`

but if I declare `function reducer(state, action)` and then above the switch statement assign `state = Immutable.Map()` it works

Comment: See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/puh0qwvp/, it is working fine. Did you not forget to add Babel to support default argument feature?

Comment: Thanks just-boris, I do have the default arguments feature setup, but there was a param being passed elsewhere in my code that was over riding it. Thanks!